# Download data from Qlik Dashboard with R

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to download data from a Qlik Dashboard (QVPROD).  It has the "Send to Excel" option when I right click over the dashboard, however I do not know how to do this in R. Also, if I want to change the date range of the data, the change in data does not show up in the URL (how the date is changes is attached in a screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mumto.jpg). Is there anyway for me to download data with a specific data range and send the data to Excel through R?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a question about R, it is entirely about Qlik. From [Qlik help](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/Ajax/WebView_StraightTable.htm) (similar for other chart objects): *"Exports possible (including selected) values to Microsoft Excel"*. This means there is likely no way to programmatically automate this. Good luck if you can get a webpage automation tool such as Selenium to accomplish this ...

Answer (score 0):

To download the data in a Mashup you can use the table-api (as documented here: http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.2/Subsystems/APIs/Content/TableAPI/exportData-method.htm)

Have a look at the following example (basically not a mashup but an extension using the same API): https://github.com/stefanwalther/sense-export/blob/master/src/swr-sense-export.js#L72

Hope this helps!